# Is a C compiler obligated to always reload const value from memory?

Tags: c, constants, compiler-optimization, constantfolding

I have a `const` variable in my embedded C program. It's defined and initialized with `0` in program code. It's placed in a special ROM area via linker script. One can change the content of the special area via special programming procedure, but it cannot be changed during main program execution.

The question is whether I have to declare the constant as `volatile`. If it's not marked as `volatile`, is the compiler allowed to replace all references to it with `0`? Or is it obligated to load it at least once during program execution?

Comment: Why are you telling the compiler that it is const when it is not?

Comment: Make it `const volatile`, that's exactly what `volatile` is for.

Comment: @EdHeal `const` doesn't mean "it won't change". It means "it won't change *via this variable*".

Comment: @Ed Heal It is a const from the main program point of view. Special programming procedure requires special boot process without starting the main program. So any attempt to modify the variable from the main program would be a bug (it's placed in ROM area). If it's defined as const there will appear a compiler error if any attempt occurs.

Comment: If it cannot be changed during program run, you can declare it `extern const` (without `volatile`) and omit an initializer.

Comment: The suggestion with extern const is good (although I'm not sure if the linker will not complain if it doesn't see a definition in code). I can also omit declaration of the const variable and refer to the address via a pointer. But the question is rather about the C language, not a best solution.

Comment: `const volatile` is very rarely used; I would expect that approach to expose compiler bugs.

Comment: `const volatile` means "I won't change this value but some other thread/process might." Can the variable change by outside means while your process/thread is running, and does the code have to be aware of the current value? Then make it `volatile`. Otherwise, just `const` is fine.

Comment: Are you looking for a portable solution or is a platform-specific one acceptable? If the latter, what's your platform?

Comment: @David Schwartz I'm interested in portable solution.

Comment: @mrn Then I think you're after the impossible because the concept of loading a value from memory has no portable meaning. For example, on typical x86 machines, it can require specific instructions to invalidate cache that there exist *no* portable way to create.

Answer (score 29):

It looks like your variable is really a constant (i.e. doesn't change during program execution) with a value unknown to the compiler. If this is the case, you can declare it like this:

```
extern const int variable;
```

(i.e. without `volatile` and without an initializer) and let the linker script or other tools set up the correct value.

The compiler will then be permitted to load it and potentially leave it in a register forever, but not replace it by 0 or any other value at compile time.

Comment: This is a good advise, however I am bound to the solution with a const defined in the code and placed in ROM correclty via linker scripts. And here comes my question - do I have to use volatile or not?

Comment: If you really need to define the variable in C, then make a separate source file containing nothing but `const int variable = 0;`, compile it separately from all your other code, and link it in.

Comment: "I am bound to the solution" I'm not sure why exactly this is called a "solution" rather than properly a "problem". but whatever it is, absent other problems, you have to use `volatile`

Answer (score 11):

If marked as `volatile` the compiler is obliged to load it from memory every time it needs it value.

If not marked as `volatile`, the compiler *may* load it once from memory, store it in a register, and use this register instead of loading it again.

A not-optimizing compiler may do this - but it also may, stupidly, load it every time. (As not reloading is in fact an optimization in itself.)

Optimizing compilers may notice the `const` and decide it can be compiled with its real, literal value; up to a point where the original constant *does not appear at all* in the `.data` section of your program. (Or maybe it does but it never gets "read".)

Since you change the value in a linker script, the compiler cannot "know" the value got changed after compiling. In that case, use `volatile`: the only way to tell the compiler not to trust that the value is known when compiling.

Comment: "Optimizing compilers may notice the const and decide it can be compiled with its real, literal value"; that's **not at all** what `const` means.

Comment: Without the context that answer provides, your phrasing is misleading enough to make people believe that `const` means more than "the compiler will complain if you modify the underlying object through this lvalue". Please be aware that this is one of the toughest myths about C, right up there with "C is portable assembly", "`inline` means that the compiler will definitely inline the function everywhere", and `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT == 32`.

Comment: @Rad Lexus "up to a point where the original constant does not appear at all in the .data section of your program." What do you mean by this?

Comment: @mm: compiling a quick test with `-O0 -S` (gcc), I get `movl _const_x(%rip), %ecx` (where `const_x = 19;` is a `const` value). Repeating with `-O1`, I get `movl $19, %edx` instead: the *literal* value. The `const_x` definition still appears in the output, but it is not used anymore. So apparently gcc does not do this, but it is possible another compiler may remove 'unused data'.

Comment: .. quite annoying, clang *always* inserts the literal value in the code, even with `-O0`. Ah for the times when compilers only did what you told them to ...

Comment: @Rhymoid: `const` *does* mean more than that. For example, C11 final draft [section 6.7.3.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p6), "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @user2357112: yeah I felt OPs backdoor way of changing a `const` value was non-standard (if only because the "linking" part moves it outside the reach and purpose of any C standard). You may want to post an answer.

Comment: @Rhymoid "that's not at all what const means" By itself it is not what `const` means, but in combination with the as-if rule, that *is* what it `const` means to an optimizing compiler. Note that @RadLexus didn't say that it would happen with certainty.

Comment: @JordanMelo Isn't the as-if rule part of the C++ semantics, and not part of the C semantics?

Comment: @Rhymoid I think you may be correct about that. My mistake. Though my point still stands that Rad Lexus didn't say it would happen with certainty. He stated that an optimizing compiler may perform that action. I don't see how his phrasing is misleading.

Comment: "*If marked as volatile the compiler is obliged to load it from memory every time it needs it value.*" This is a common myth. Nothing about the semantics of `volatile` prohibit the value from being cached, and if you look at the assembler output of volatile accesses on typical compilers, you will see that they just perform a normal cached read with no special effort to force a read from memory.

Comment: "the compiler is obliged to load it from memory" I thought cpu core is the one who load variable from memory.. Not compiler.

Comment: @electro: "The compiler is obliged to [emit asm instructions that] load it from memory".  Describing the actions of the generated machine code as the compiler doing them is typical short-hand.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Loads come from "memory" as in the memory hierarchy, not necessarily from DRAM. I don't have a problem with that phrasing. Since caches are coherent in normal systems, it works to think of "memory" as the domain that loads/stores access.  (If you have a hybrid system like an ARM microcontroller and DSP with non-coherent shared memory, you wouldn't be running threads of the same program across the different domains, and then you would need to distinguish CPU cache from DRAM and worry about write-back).  MMIO regions need to be marked uncacheable to work correctly.

Comment: What this answer doesn't mention is that `const int x = 10;` might be loaded *zero* times by code that uses `x`, instead using it as an immediate in the machine code.  Or even baking it in to how the code is structured.  (e.g. fully unroll a loop of `const int n` iteration, or multiply by 10 with shift/add instructions that don't involve a `10` anywhere, like x86 compilers do: https://godbolt.org/z/oc7dKfhYo .  Or `return x*5` becomes `return 50`, again with no static data read at all for `const int x = 10`.  But yes, `volatile` defeats that as well.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't know what it means to say loads come from the memory hierarchy. Where else could they possibly come from? If "memory" doesn't refer to anything specific, it's just saying that loads get a value from somewhere. If caches are part of the memory hierarchy, then so are prefetches and re-using cached values that came from the memory hierarchy still come from the memory hierarchy. Either this means something or it doesn't, and it seems to me like it doesn't.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: IDK man, it seems clear enough to me.  The "memory" address-space you load from and store to in a normal program is both virtualized (paging) and cached (CPU caches), but coherent between threads.  The compiler can't reuse a value from a register (which some people confusingly call caching, leading to misconceptions about bypassing CPU cache). `volatile` just means a load or store will happen in the asm.  It's best to say that to get beginners on the same page, but "accessing memory" is a reasonable short-hand as long as it's understood that doesn't mean "DRAM" in this context.

Comment: @PeterCordes It's impossible for volatile to mean that a load or store will happen in the asm because volatile is specified by a standard that doesn't even make the assumption that code is compiled into assembly language. Some platforms might decide that's a reasonable way to get the result the standard specifies, but that can't be what the standard specifies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Ok fine, it means that in practice for implementations that compile to code for stored-program computers (so asm instructions are a thing) and where data access to memory is possible, not just registers.  (At least by de-facto agreement of compiler developers of how to interpret the language in the standard.)  If you were compiling a C++ function or program to an FPGA pipeline that took inputs and produced outputs, yeah `volatile` couldn't have that meaning. But for the foreseeable future, I think it's a reasonable thing to say, at least with a disclaimer about "normal systems"

Comment: @PeterCordes So then do you agree with me that "If marked as volatile the compiler is obliged to load it from memory every time it needs it value" is a myth? At best, it's a description of what some platforms happen to do. But there is no such obligation found anywhere. And it's not even clear what "from memory" means as from the memory hierarchy is the only place a load can come from anyway almost by definition.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I wouldn't say it's a myth.  At best it's a useful description of the practical consequence on real implementations, if the speaker and audience understand what's meant by "memory".  I do agree it's not a very good description for an answer like this where the audience includes people who don't already know how CPUs and asm work, and how compilers do things.  Re: where else could you load from? For a constant, loading a register from an immediate is a possibility, not using the storage space for non-volatile `const int foo = 1`, e.g. return foo becomes RV32 `li a0, 1` / `ret`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Do you know of any real C implementations where `volatile` doesn't result in a compiler emitting load/store instructions?  Especially one that compiles for an embedded system with ROM, which is the context of this question.  Sure a hypothetical implementation for a model of computation other than a RAM machine might be possible, but C's abstract machine does include the notion of memory and addresses, and every object having an address, and thus bytes in memory that can be loaded from / stored to.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've been at this long enough to see *massive* damage done by people confusing what standards *oblige* implementations to do with what every implementation to date has chosen to do. This particular error is a huge reason for software needlessly breaking with new CPUs, new compiler optimizations, or new OS versions. Every real implementation behave a particular way until they make one that doesn't. And then code that relied on "guarantees" that didn't actually exist breaks, sometimes in subtle horrible ways.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Ok, I see your point from that perspective, but this isn't just an arbitrary implementation choice like that misaligned `int*` loads in C compiled for x86 used to "work" despite explicitly being UB. `volatile` is hard to formally define because the real meaning is in a domain outside the abstract machine.  Do you disagree with this answer's overall point that `const volatile int foo = 123;` would prevent inlining or constant-propagation, and make it possible to change the actual value in the binary image at just this one location without changing the source and recompiling?

Comment: @PeterCordes No, I wouldn't. Nothing in the standard requires it. If it happens to work in some cases, then great, use it. But relying on it to work is madness.